# Deploying PhoneGap Applications to Web instead of to App Store

Tags: iphone, mobile, cordova, jqtouch

I've built a web platform where one small feature allows users to contribute data to the system. Now that smartphones are so common, I want to build an app that allows people to submit some information, along with a camera photo and their GPS location.

As our users use varying phones, I'd like to build a single universal app to accomplish that task. I found PhoneGap online for that very purpose, but I have a question: **can PhoneGap applications be deployed to the web instead of to app stores?** By that, I'm asking whether camera and geolocation functionality will still work if the HTML and Javascript files are placed on a web server.

If not, I've also seen JQTouch. **Can I use JQTouch instead for such camera and GPS functionality?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I believe that a PhoneGap application is running inside an "interpreter" that will let you access the Camera Accelerometer and so on... So this means that it cannot run outside an Application. So **no web deployement**
- jQTouch is a UI framework, so **no access to Camera or GPS**
- You can **use HTML5 to access location** via web

Comment: jQTouch does provide an extension that can get the location information. http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/source/browse/trunk/extensions/jqt.location.js?r=87

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can deploy phonegap apps with the market.
At least, if it's not an iPhone.
You should still compile the applications and make the user download them.

jQTouch is just for the GUI, much like sencha and jQuery Mobile.
HTML5 would give you a gps functionality, but that doesn't work on most phones yet (symbian and BB and WP make up about 50% of the market if not more).

Answer (score 0):

Great Idea Maxim, 
Maxim you can deploy your app outside the app store and it can access the native feature, but in that case it will be a webApp And it will be accessible from every mobile platform.

If you want that as an app(Native), You have a submit it into AppStore (For IOS) and for android you can deploy it on other markets also.